# nodejs - cluster disconnect/shutdown

Tags: node.js

The `cluster` modules in nodejs has the `exit`, `disconnect`, and `death` events. Which functions should the worker invoke in order to issue such events?

I have tried `cluster.worker.X()` where X is either `close`, `end`, `diconnect`, etc.
with the same breath, how to issue `end` event for the `http.createServer()`?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe these events should be invoked directly. They exists for us to be able to react to events in the lifecycle of the cluster. Here's how to indirectly invoke them:

**exit**

```
// from the worker
process.exit()
```

**disconnect**

```
// from the master
var worker = cluster.fork()
worker.disconnect()
```

**death** (deprecated)

[Renamed to 'exit'](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.6-and-v0.8) in v0.8.0 (see above).